# How to get property (Account is disabled) in LDAP C#

Tags: c#, ldap

How get property account is disabled?
I have a list of contacts and want to know whether a worker is active

[this property - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWYxR.jpg)

My getter information about an employee with Active Directory. I need a property that determines whether a worker is active.

```
 public List<string> SomeInformation()
    {
        List<string> lista = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = SearchRoot;
            DirectoryEntry gbvision = myLdapConnection.Children.Find("OU=WN");
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(gbvision);

            search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))";



            // create an array of properties that we would like and  
            // add them to the search object  

            string[] requiredProperties = new string[] { "cn", "mail", "telephoneNumber", "title", "mobile", "department" };

            foreach (String property in requiredProperties)
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(property);


            foreach (SearchResult result in search.FindAll())
            {

                if (result != null)
                {
                    foreach (String property in requiredProperties)
                    {
                        foreach (Object myCollection in result.Properties[property])
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-20} : {1}", property, myCollection.ToString()));
                            lista.Add(property + myCollection);
                        }
                    }
                    lista.Add("END");


                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("User not found!");
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught:\n\n" + e.ToString());
        }
        return lista;

    }
```

Comment: I think you want the `userAccountControl` property, which you would check for `ACCOUNTDISABLE   (2, 0x0002)` - see e.g. [PowerShell Script to Query UserAccountControl Flags](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/muaddib/2014/03/30/powershell-script-to-query-useraccountcontrol-flags/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this LDAP filter to see if the account is disabled:

```
(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)
```

So to get active users:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))
```

Comment: not working for OpenLDAP.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response and after using this filter does not appear to me a list of users. I found a solution for this and it is:

```
var accountIsDisabled = Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(flag) & 0x0002);
```